# Linux ловилка клавиатурных событий

Tags: linux, клавиатура

В каком-то вопросе, вроде, на `stackoverflow` английском читал инструкцию по пользованию какой-то утилиты, которая "вешает" реакцию на определенные нажатия на клавиатуре. Забыл, как она называется и не могу нагуглить.
Там вроде надо было узнать коды клавиш и использовать их в качестве аргументов, а в качестве реакции задать имя скрипта. В интернете пока вижу только всякую нерелевантную ерунду вроде программ на питоне или листингов с решениями, как реализовать ловлю событий клавиатуры в своей программе.

**Что это за утилита, или можно без утилиты отредактировать как-то прерывания таким образом, чтобы я мог из `X` (Xvesa) переходить в консоль не только Ctrl+Alt+Fn, но и Alt+Tab?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен [Xbindkeys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)).

При настройке для перехода в консоль можно использовать команду `chvt`. Вот [пример](https://the-bosha.ru/2010/03/16/chvt/) на русском, где делают похожее на то, что нужно вам.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за предыдущий ответ, он пригодился, но я все-таки заодно откопал в истории браузера тот вопрос с забытой *keyboard shortcut* утилитой. Это демон `actkbd`